# Pythonic way to get .03 from 3%

Tags: python

I can convert `%` to decimal a few ways, such as extracting the int part using a regex and divide by `100` or split by `'%'` and `int()` the first part. But I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Erm, how is parsing the number not "Pythonic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-strip the percent, parse as float, and divide by 100:

```
float(your_string.rstrip('%')) / 100.0
```

This will allow multiple `%`, though, which may or may not be a good thing. If you know that the last character will *always* be a `%`, you can just slice the string:

```
float(your_string[:-1]) / 100.0
```

Comment: Might also be pythonic to do `your_string[:-1]` since it avoids a function call, but your case does take into account numbers without the `%`.

Comment: @Serdalis: `[:-1]` isn't truly without a function call; it will call `__getitem__`, passing it a `slice` object.

Comment: @Serdalis `.rstrip('%')` is much more clear and explicit. Shorter code does not mean more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

The number should come with one (and only one) %-sign, and at the end of the string:

```
def perc2num(p):
    p = p.strip() # get rid of whitespace after the %
    if p.endswith('%') and p.count('%') == 1:
        return float(p[:-1])
    else:
        raise ValueError('Not a percentage.')
```

The `float()` conversion will strip whitespace between the number and %.

Test:

```
In [11]: perc2num('3.5%')
Out[11]: 3.5

In [12]: perc2num('-0.2')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-9a6733e653ff> in <module>()
----> 1 perc2num('-0.2')

<ipython-input-10-44f49dc456d1> in perc2num(p)
      3         return float(p[:-1])
      4     else:
----> 5         raise ValueError('Not a percentage.')

ValueError: Not a percentage.

In [13]: perc2num('-7%')
Out[13]: -7.0

In [15]: perc2num('  23%')
Out[15]: 23.0

In [16]: perc2num('  14.5 %')
Out[16]: 14.5

In [17]: perc2num('  -21.8 %  ')
Out[17]: -21.8
```